# Reset forms in Angular2

Tags: angular

can someone tell me how to reset form after i submit one in Angular2?

```html
<div class="field" [ngClass]="{error: !articleForm.find('link').valid && articleForm.find('link').touched}">
    <label>Link:</label>
    <input type="text" name="link" [ngFormControl]="articleForm.controls['link']"/>
</div>
```

The problem is that after submit form remain '.touched'. I need to reset it.
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 4):

In rc5, there is a reset() method in the FormGroup.

```
this.form.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understant your login in ngFormControl .

But suppose your Form Group name is **submitGroup** and formControlName is **name** then code will look like something below :

```
this.submitGroup.reset({
      'name': ''
});
```